# Perfectly working curl command fails when executed in a groovy script

Tags: curl, groovy, gitblit

I have a post commit hook (a groovy script) in gitblit to invoke a REST endpoint. In this script I am executing a curl command. But it seems to fail. The curl command works fine when executed from the commandline.

Following is my groovy script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy


def repoUrl= "https://gitblit.myhost.com/git/" + repository + ".git"
json='{"repository":{"url":"'+repoUrl+'"}}'

def response = "curl -v -k -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '${json}' https://username:password@anotherhost.com:9443/restendpoint".execute().text
println response
```

repository is passed by gitblit to this script and I have verified it.

Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: Can you print out the GString before executing it to ensure it's producing the command you expect?

Comment: What exactly failes? Can You please make Your question more precise?

Answer (score 30):

I couldn't reproduce your problem with your example, but i will try a wild guess:

First, use the list `execute()` version, so you don't have problems with tokens:

```
process = [ 'bash', '-c', "curl -v -k -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '${json}' https://username:password@anotherhost.com:9443/restendpoint" ].execute()
```

Second, read both error and output from the process:

```
process.waitFor()
println process.err.text
println process.text
```

The `err` may give out what is going on

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for hours, but your solution worked for me. Why does the list version have to be used instead of a regular string?

Comment: @Jamil, i guess it's because the runtime execution can do the correct separation of arguments/commands and escaping, otherwise it might get ambiguous.

Comment: If anyone is curious, there is a brief explanation on separating arguments here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy.

Comment: I think the `.text` is wrong in the first code block, isn't it?

Comment: How do we retrieve HTTP code from groovy execute method ?

Answer (score 24):

I was able to get this working by passing all the string in my curl command in an array. Following is how I did it.

```
def response = ["curl", "-k", "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "${json}", "https://username:password@myhost.com:9443/restendpoint"].execute().text
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ‘running-forever’ process (this happens on some Windows env when output exceeds 4096 bytes) add initial size to ByteArrayOutputStream

```
def initialSize = 4096
def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def err = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
proc.waitFor()
```

Comment: Having a hard time seeing how this is really answering the question asked here...

Comment: @AndrewBarber not doing this can cause hanging processes. The asker didn't specify how the command failed so it's a fair guess, and we're stuck guessing anyway.

Comment: I'm actually googling to solve a "running forever" process process issue (non windows) and since this was the first post I found relating to it, I wanted to say thanks for posting. Even though its not really related to OP's question, I think its sending me down the path toward fixing my issue, so thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In Curl Post -- In-F option  - wrap the entire param with double quotes .Don't forget to escape the double quotes to get syntax right.
Example Below:

def response = "curl -u admin:admin -F\"jcr:content/par/address/address1=2/3 Market Place\" http://localhost:4502/content/datasource/branches".execute().text