# Groovy & Jenkins - capture curl output to a file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to fill out a Dynamic Parameter box in Jenkins.

My Groovy script should do the following:

1. Collect JSON output in a file.
2. Parse JSON output in order to get some specific values .
3. Shows those values in a list in Dynamic Parameter of Jenkins in order to choose one of them.

Can you help me with the Groovy script? No idea about Groovy :-(.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do 1.? See [Groovy – Learn](http://groovy-lang.org/learn.html), [Groovy – Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html), [how to parse json using groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6688090/1744774), etc.

Comment: I should run a curl command in order to get my json output file first and then I have to get some information from this json file. "jsonSlurper.parseText" support curl execution? my curl command has the following shape: curl -s ''$URL' -u $USERKEY

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to write the JSON data to a file to achieve this.

Taking [Perfectly working curl command fails when executed in a groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23742419/1744774) and [Parsing and producing JSON, 1. JsonSlurper](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) as foundation do the following in a Dynamic Parameter's script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

url= "http://user:pwd@jenkins/api/json"
process = [ 'bash', '-c',  "curl ${url}" ].execute()
process.waitFor()
//println process.err.text  // for debugging in Jenkins' Script Console
//println process.text
info = new JsonSlurper().parseText(process.text)
return info._class
```

Output at *Build with Parameters*:

> This build requires parameters:
>
> Dynamic Parameter `hudson.model.Hudson`